# Did Jesus mislead his followers when he claimed that kingdom of God would come to Earth during their lifetime?

Tags: kingdom-of-god

When Jesus was speaking about the imminence of God's kingdom he meant God's kingdom on Earth, not in heaven. Jesus urged his followers to repent and change their ways because God was coming to Earth to judge people and establish his kingdom. Jesus said that, upon coming, God would raise from the dead those on God's side and to annihilate wicked ones. So Jesus was clearly speaking about God's earthly kingdom. Since no people were ever raised from the dead it is logical to conclude that Jesus's prophesy was inaccurate.

Comment: Please don't put your own answer in the question itself. You can [edit] this to remove your answer and just keep the question the question.

Comment: I think there's the essence of a great question here, but 1. it could use some scriptural references (Jesus says what exactly, where exactly in the Bible?), and 2. as @curiousdannii says, leave it as a question instead of making it into a statement.

Answer (score 3):

Well, ***did*** Jesus ever say to his disciples, "The Kingdom of God will come to Earth during your lifetimes"? You offer no scripture that even indicates such a suggestion on Jesus' part.

Second questionable claim is whether Jesus ever said God was coming to Earth to judge people and establish his kingdom. On the contrary, Jesus said ***he*** would judge the world at his second coming, that the Father would not judge as he had committed all judging to him (John 5:22) but at Christ's first coming, he had not come to judge the world (John 12:47) but to save that. Having achieved that at his first time on earth, the second time ***will*** be to judge the world (Rev. 1:7 & 6:16-17).

Third questionable claim is that "God would raise from the dead those on God's side and to annihilate wicked ones."  Jesus said ***he*** will call forth from the graves every person who has ever died, to judge them (John 11:24-26 & Rev.20:11-15 where those not found written in the Lamb's book of Life will be sent to everlasting punishment in the eternally burning sulphuric lake).

This means that the question itself may be misleading, as there is no scriptural ground established for the three claims in it. This seems to be a particular interpretation that some groups hold to (especially that of 'annihilationism'). A question based on opinion is likely to lead to answers based on opinion, which will get us nowhere. If you can give a scriptural basis for the actual question - Jesus misleading his followers by claiming that the Kingdom of God would come to Earth during their lifetime - then I can add to my answer here.

Answer (score 1):

No, Jesus didn't mislead as in *lie*. But it does appear that he didn't know when he would return to earth to claim his throne over earth with his resurrected saints. You are right that he did that infer that it was imminent, we do not know why he had this understanding.

> “But about that day or hour no one knows, not even the angels in heaven, nor the son, but only the Father. Mark 13:32, Matt 24:36

So only God knew, Jesus did not. We also know that God sent Jesus toward the end of this age, so it would be understandable to think it was soon.

> God, having spoken long ago to our fathers in the prophets in many portions and in many ways, - **in these last days** - has spoken to us in His Son Heb 1:1-2

Whoever wrote Hebrews also had this urgency that is right through the NT.

However, "God would raise from the dead those on God's side and to annihilate wicked ones" is incorrect.

After Jesus' return, there begins a 1000 year restoration of earth in which the remnant of humanity would be taught the ways of God free from Satan's influence.

> an angel. . . seized the dragon, the ancient serpent, who is the devil and Satan, and bound him for a thousand years. And he cast him into the abyss, and shut and sealed it over him, so that he should not deceive the nations any longer Rev 20:2-

After this Kingdom Millennium, Satan would be released and all mankind that ever lived would be raised to physical life and the final judgement. This is all part of God's plan to SAVE His creation, not destroy it or torture it for ever.
Any not willing to freely choose God over the devil will suffer the second death and cease to exist. Pretty much all explained [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/36185/does-matthew-1015-refer-to-different-degrees-of-torment-punishment-in-the-etern/66535#66535) with scriptures.

Comment: Do you think Jesus had a wrong understanding?